# How to stub property getter?

Tags: c#, mocking, moq

I use [Moq](https://github.com/Moq/moq4). I want to stub a property getter in mock object:

```
var db = new Lazy<DatabaseContext>(DatabaseContextFactory.Create);
var mock = new Mock<IDocumentOperationContext>();

// stub "Database" property getter
mock.SetupGet(_ => _.Database).Stub(_ => db.Value);
```

But it throws an exception:

```
System.InvalidOperationExceptionThe object 'IDocumentOperationContext _ => _.Database' is not a mocked object.
```

I don't want to implement `IDocumentOperationContext` or to stub with already existing `DatabaseContext` object.

How to achieve the goal? Is it possible in another Mocking library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.Returns` instead of `.Stub`.